# Edit body background color when hovering another div

Tags: hover

I want to edit the background color when hovering the title of my tumblr website

```
.sidebar .title h1:hover body {
    background: red;
}
```

the code doesn't work. I'm not familiar with javascript and I wanted to know if it's possible with css. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS rules only work within the element specified. So, you will not be able to do what you want only in CSS. However, using Javascript on your tumblr can be fairly easy and you'll be able to do what you want with the following:

Your title code will look like:

```
<h1 onmouseenter="changeBodyBackgroundColor()">My Title</h1>
```

The add the following in the `<head></head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeBodyBackgroundColor() {
    document.body.style.background = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the background to change only on hover. I tried `onmouseover` instead of `onmouseenter` but it doesn't work.